# c++ program that sum values from user and display average

Tags: c++

I have an assignment regarding display the average of 10 given grades in an array. Now I need to not take into account grades with the value -1. In this case, -1 indicates the assignment was not completed yet so it should not factor in the average.
example:

```
Grade 1: 90
Grade 2: 86
Grade 3: 95
Grade 4: 76
Grade 5: 92
Grade 6: 83
Grade 7: 100
Grade 8: 87
Grade 9: 91
Grade 10: -1
Average Grade: 88%  //Notice how the -1 for the 10th grade is not factored into the average.
Example 2
Grade 1: -1
Grade 2: -1
Grade 3: -1
Grade 4: -1
Grade 5: -1
Grade 6: -1
Grade 7: -1
Grade 8: -1
Grade 9: -1
Grade 10: -1
Average Grade: ---%
```

Since all of the grades are `-1`, there is no average. You will need to handle this condition.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_GRADES 10

void getGrades(int grades[], int num)
{
for(int iGrades = 0; iGrades < num; iGrades++)
{
    cout << "Grade " << iGrades + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> grades[iGrades];
}
return;
}

int averageGrades(int grades[], int num)
{
int average;
int sum;
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    sum+=grades[i];
}
average = sum / num;
return average;
}

 int main()
{
int grades[NUM_GRADES];
averageGrades(grades, NUM_GRADES);
getGrades(grades, NUM_GRADES);

cout << "Average Grade: "
<< averageGrades(grades, NUM_GRADES)
<< "%\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to C++. It's time to learn about proper indentation and your new friend [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You're looking for an `if` statement.

Comment: This appears to be a problem caused by `sum` being used before being initialized. Check that your compiler warnings are turned on because this should get flagged. There's also no need for the `average` variable as you can `return sum/num`.

Comment: Why are you calling `averageGrades()` *before* you call `getGrades()`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `sum` appears to be, it's not initialized to zero.

Comment: @tadman I believe your comment said `average` was uninitialized at the time of my reply, though I may have misread. I've since deleted it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, I corrected that mistake.

Comment: `num` needs to be calculated from the number of grades that are not `-1`

Comment: thank you guys for your comments, I'm really new in c++, I found an answer  using an if statement after the for loop in averageGrades() function. if(grades[i] > = 0{ count ++; sum+=grades[i]; then return  sum/count; that will ignore all numbers that are less than 0

Comment: @tadman I havent learn about std::vector yet hehe

Comment: @Barmar calling one function or another first doesnt change anything in this case isnt it?

Comment: @David Well, you're causing undefined behavior, because you're adding up numbers in an array that was never initialized. But you're also ignoring the return value of the first call.

Comment: @Barmar so I need to follow the order of the functions in the program to be more organized right? thank you!

Comment: You need to be aware of dependencies. You can't do something that depends on the value of a variable until *after* you assign that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`averageGrades()` needs an `if` statement to skip the `-1` grades, and also a counter of the number of valid grades. It also needs to initialize `sum` to `0` before it can add to it.

You can return `-1` from the function to indicate that there was no average.

```
int averageGrades(int grades[], int num)
{
    int average;
    int sum = 0, gradeCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (grades[i] != -1) {
            sum+=grades[i];
            gradeCount++;
        }
    }
    if (gradeCount > 0) {
        average = sum / gradeCount;
    } else {
        average = -1;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Then you need to check for this special return value when printing the result in `main()`, so you can show `---` instead of the number.

```
int avg = averageGrades(grades, NUM_GRADES);
cout << "Average Grade: ";
if (avg == -1) {
    cout << "---";
} else {
    cout << avg;
}
cout << "%\n";
```

Comment: in the if(grades[i] != -1) can we change it for grades[i]>= 0 so we can ignore every negative number?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. The assignment says `-1` is the indicator, it doesn't say anything about other negative numbers.